# SQL / Excel: Make Excel table of SQL entries per hour

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel

I have a question about moving some SQL query into Excel. So I currently have a table like this (that I got from SQL):

```
        Date        | Name
--------------------------
2016-08-09 06:05:22 | Jeff
2016-08-09 06:08:42 | Jeff
2016-08-09 06:43:16 | Jeff
2016-08-09 07:05:22 | Jeff
2016-08-09 07:33:04 | Alex
2016-08-09 09:33:54 | Alex
2016-08-09 10:45:02 | Sara
```

And what I'm looking to do is build an excel table that displays, separated by hour, how many times each person's name appears. So under a 6 o'clock column I'd want there to be a 3 next to Jeff and 0's for everyone else. At 7 I'd want a 1 for Jeff and a 1 for Alex. And at 9 and 10, I'd want a 1 for Alex and a 1 for Sara, respectively.

Here's what I'd like it to look like:

```
     | 06 | 07 | 08 | 09 | 10 | 11
----------------------------------
Jeff | 3  | 1  | 0  | 0  | 0  | 0
Alex | 0  | 1  | 0  | 1  | 0  | 0
Sara | 0  | 0  | 0  | 0  | 1  | 0
```

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Comment: PIVOT comes to mind.

Comment: @Nicarus Microsoft SQL server management studio

Comment: SQL Server - which version (2008 R2, 2012, etc?). Server Management Studio (SSMS) is just the IDE, FYI.

Comment: This is not as exciting as T-SQL, but you can also use Excel's pivot table feature

Comment: Do you want the results in SQL or Excel? You can pivot in both as people have stated. Excel is easier as you can change it on the fly quickly but if there is a specific output that will remain constant then you can do it in SSMS

Comment: @Nicarus 2012. Sorry, I'm a SQL noob

Comment: @scsimon I want the results in Excel so I'll try out some pivot tables

Comment: PIVOT isn't hard in SQL but it's more intuitive in Excel. I'd go with the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a quick and dirty way to get that result in SQL:

```
SELECT
    name,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEPART(HOUR,[Date]) = 0 THEN 1 END) AS [00],
    COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEPART(HOUR,[Date]) = 1 THEN 1 END) AS [01],
    COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEPART(HOUR,[Date]) = 2 THEN 1 END) AS [02],
    COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEPART(HOUR,[Date]) = 3 THEN 1 END) AS [03],
    COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEPART(HOUR,[Date]) = 4 THEN 1 END) AS [04],
    COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEPART(HOUR,[Date]) = 5 THEN 1 END) AS [05],
    COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEPART(HOUR,[Date]) = 6 THEN 1 END) AS [06],
    COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEPART(HOUR,[Date]) = 7 THEN 1 END) AS [07],
    COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEPART(HOUR,[Date]) = 8 THEN 1 END) AS [08],
    COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEPART(HOUR,[Date]) = 9 THEN 1 END) AS [09],
    COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEPART(HOUR,[Date]) = 10 THEN 1 END) AS [10],
    COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEPART(HOUR,[Date]) = 11 THEN 1 END) AS [11],
    COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEPART(HOUR,[Date]) = 12 THEN 1 END) AS [12],
    COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEPART(HOUR,[Date]) = 13 THEN 1 END) AS [13],
    COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEPART(HOUR,[Date]) = 14 THEN 1 END) AS [14],
    COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEPART(HOUR,[Date]) = 15 THEN 1 END) AS [15],
    COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEPART(HOUR,[Date]) = 16 THEN 1 END) AS [16],
    COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEPART(HOUR,[Date]) = 17 THEN 1 END) AS [17],
    COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEPART(HOUR,[Date]) = 18 THEN 1 END) AS [18],
    COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEPART(HOUR,[Date]) = 19 THEN 1 END) AS [19],
    COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEPART(HOUR,[Date]) = 20 THEN 1 END) AS [20],
    COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEPART(HOUR,[Date]) = 21 THEN 1 END) AS [21],
    COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEPART(HOUR,[Date]) = 22 THEN 1 END) AS [22],
    COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEPART(HOUR,[Date]) = 23 THEN 1 END) AS [23]
FROM
    mytable -- Replace with the name of your table
GROUP BY
    name
```

This will create a column for each hour base on if the individual (`name`) has a record within that hour.

---

Here it is using the `PIVOT` syntax:

```
WITH mycte AS (
   -- To make sure that hours with no individuals (`name`), we full join to all possible hours (0-23)
SELECT
    hr.hour_number,
    mt.name,
    mt.[Date]
FROM
    (
    VALUES
        (0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),
        (10),(11),(12),(13),(14),(15),(16),(17),
        (18),(19),(20),(21),(22),(23)
    ) hr (hour_number)
FULL JOIN
    mytable mt
    ON  (hr.hour_number = DATEPART(HOUR,mt.datet))
GROUP BY
    hr.hour_number,
    mt.name,
    mt.[Date]
)

-- This is the actual pivot. Had we not done the work above, hours were the value was 0 for all `name`s would not appear
SELECT
    name,
    [0],[1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12],
    [13],[14],[15],[16],[17],[18],[19],[20],[21],[22],[23]
FROM
    mycte
PIVOT
    (
    COUNT([Date]) FOR hour_number IN (
        [0],[1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12],
        [13],[14],[15],[16],[17],[18],[19],[20],[21],[22],[23]
        )
    ) p
WHERE
    name IS NOT NULL -- This ensure only records associated to a name is returned
```

Comment: That's pretty awesome. Everything works about that except the tally per hour is inflated somehow. Where the number for 15:00 should be 2, it's 151 for example. The zeros are correct though. Any ideas? But either way thanks, that's super helpful!

Comment: Never mind, I found a bunch of repeats in the table that I'll need to get rid of. Works great! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

One option is to extract the time element with:

```
=INT(MOD(A2,1)*24)
```

copied down to suit.

This takes the time element of Date/Time, converts it to hours and rounds.

And then pivot:

[image: SO38885347 example]

To ensure a complete set of times (eg include `8`) you would need to add those that are missing to your source data.

There is an option to display `0`s rather than blanks, if you want them.

The order of names is alphabetical by default but may be adjusted 'manually'.

Comment: That expression is from another planet. Bookmarked! :P

Comment: Thanks! I tried that and it worked pretty well, I'll need some practice with pivot tables to get this working. But thanks for the response!